# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/ardia/service/ComposantService; with spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, jsf-2

I have a web application wich uses JSF 2.0, Spring 3.0 and Hibernate 4. After two days of setup I finally got a list in my datatable, but I faced a problem as well. I can tell that because I saw errors in console on service class usage:

My service class:

```
package com.ardia.service; 
@Service("compService")
@Transactional
public class ComposantImp implements ComposantService {


    @Autowired
    SessionFactory sessionFactory;


    @Override
    public void inserComposant(Composant comp) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(comp);
    }

    @Override
    public Composant getComposantById(int compId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (Composant) sessionFactory.
                  getCurrentSession().
                  get(Composant.class, compId);
    }

    @Override
    public Composant getComposant(String compname) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Composant> getComposants() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.
                  getCurrentSession().
                  createCriteria(Composant.class);
                return criteria.list();
    }

}
```

My bean class:

```
package com.ardia.beans;
import java.util.List;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import com.ardia.model.Composant;
import com.ardia.service.ComposantService;

@ManagedBean(name="userMB")
@SessionScoped
public class Composantbeam {

    @ManagedProperty(value="#{compService}")
    ComposantService service;

    private List<Composant> list;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        list=service.getComposants();
    }

    public List<Composant> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<Composant> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    public ComposantService getService() {
        return service;
    }

    public void setService(ComposantService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

}
```

My faces-config.xml:

```
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <application>
        <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
    </application>
</faces-config>
```

My web.xml:

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>PFE</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/application.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/Test.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Spring configuration:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd">

       <context:component-scan base-package="ardia.beans" />
       <context:component-scan base-package="com.ardia.service" />
       <!-- Data Source Declaration -->
       <bean id="DataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" >
           <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
           <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql:PFE" />
           <property name="username" value="postgres" />
           <property name="password" value="root" />
       </bean>
       <!-- Session Factory Declaration -->
       <bean id="SessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
           <property name="dataSource" ref="DataSource" />
           <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.ardia.model" />
           <property name="hibernateProperties">
               <props>
                   <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</prop>
                   <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
               </props>
           </property>
       </bean>
      <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
     <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager" >
         <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory"/>
     </bean>
 </beans>
```

Data table in my JSF page works and returns the list of values.

But eventually I get the following error:

```
avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext listenerStart
Grave: Exception lors de l'envoi de l'évènement contexte initialisé (context initialized) à l'instance de classe d'écoute (listener) com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Lcom/ardia/service/ComposantService;
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.collectAnnotatedFields(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:242)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.getBeanInfo(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:151)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.process(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:137)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.ManagedBeanConfigHandler.push(ManagedBeanConfigHandler.java:123)
    at com.sun.faces.application.annotation.AnnotationManager.applyConfigAnntations(AnnotationManager.java:196)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.processAnnotations(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:328)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.process(ManagedBeanConfigProcessor.java:244)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ValidatorConfigProcessor.process(ValidatorConfigProcessor.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ConverterConfigProcessor.process(ConverterConfigProcessor.java:126)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ComponentConfigProcessor.process(ComponentConfigProcessor.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.ApplicationConfigProcessor.process(ApplicationConfigProcessor.java:337)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.LifecycleConfigProcessor.process(LifecycleConfigProcessor.java:116)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.AbstractConfigProcessor.invokeNext(AbstractConfigProcessor.java:114)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:223)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:335)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:223)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4765)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5260)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1525)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ardia.service.ComposantService
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
    ... 34 more

avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Error listenerStart
avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
Grave: Erreur de démarrage du contexte [/testefzefsdfsdfdfg] suite aux erreurs précédentes
avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8585"]
avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
Infos: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8010"]
avr. 21, 2013 12:41:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
Infos: Server startup in 15288 ms
```

I don't have a class named `Lcom.ardia.service` but I have `com.ardia.service`.

Answer (score -1):

I removed the annotation from my service class.

Creation of the service manually via Spring configuration solved my issue. This is the relevant part of configuration:

```
<bean id="compService" class="com.ardia.service.ComposantImp">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="SessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

It turns out that annotations are not supported with JSF and Hibernate...

Comment: As with most `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`s it's a classloading issue indicating that you have duplicate versions of the same class (or jar) on the classpath. Getting rid of the annotation eliminated the need to load the class and that's why it's working